# Как подобрать переменную, состоящую из 18 элементов? Переменная должна удовлетворять нескольким условиям

Tags: python

## Суть задачи - найти минимальную допустимую итоговую цену. Для этого нужно подобрать переменную из 18 элементов. Как это сделать?

```
#вводные:
prices = [124200  91000 124200  67500  96500  70500 114400  83200  75000  57600
  45600  30200  30200  30000  30000  30000  30000  30000]

budget_split = [0.20419895 0.2017904  0.19960125 0.00869134 0.02313767 0.00428459
 0.21892543 0.04802103 0.05803968 0.01338142 0.00342614 0.00233065
 0.00138871 0.00095321 0.0017216  0.00311734 0.0023248  0.00466578]

aff = [0.93972462 0.82758114 0.94904232 0.55632674 1.1949657  0.43475197
 0.92143587 1.18005534 1.02297964 1.71846277 1.2283596  0.58841192
 2.20166106 0.97470404 1.2394015  0.65835301 0.58835556 1.93003018]


#prices - цены, Const
#budget_split- процентное распределение бюджета
#aff - спец. коэф, Const
#prices,aff,budget_split- каждый состоит из 18 элементов

#Итоговая цена определяется по формуле:
n = budget_split 
m = (1 / (prices / aff))
price_general = sum(n) / sum(n * m)

#При использовании базового budget_split итоговая цена составит 103300.99270623508

#Нужно подобрать все возможные вариации budget_split_new в рамках заданных условий и подставить в уравнение.
budget_split_new = (x0,x1,x2,x3,...,x16,x17)

#При этом есть 3 обязательных условия для подбираемого budget_split_new:
#1)
#условия для сумм некоторых элементов budget_split_new:
#x0+x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x16+x17 = 0.64869478 #это первые 6 элементов и последние 2
#x0+x1+x2+x6 = 0.82451603
#условие для суммы всех элементов budget_split_new:
#sum(budget_split_new) = 1

#2)В то же время, каждый из 18 элементов budget_split_new находится в заданном диапазоне (+-50% от соответствующих значений budget_split)
#0.001 – это шаг перебора возможных вариантов

x0 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[0] * 0.5), (budget_split[0] * 1.5), 0.001))
x1 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[1] * 0.5), (budget_split[1] * 1.5), 0.001))
x2 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[2] * 0.5), (budget_split[2] * 1.5), 0.001))
x3 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[3] * 0.5), (budget_split[3] * 1.5), 0.001))
x4 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[4] * 0.5), (budget_split[4] * 1.5), 0.001))
x5 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[5] * 0.5), (budget_split[5] * 1.5), 0.001))
x6 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[6] * 0.5), (budget_split[6] * 1.5), 0.001))
x7 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[7] * 0.5), (budget_split[7] * 1.5), 0.001))
x8 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[8] * 0.5), (budget_split[8] * 1.5), 0.001))
x9 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[9] * 0.5), (budget_split[9] * 1.5), 0.001))
x10 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[10] * 0.5), (budget_split[10] * 1.5), 0.001))
x11 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[11] * 0.5), (budget_split[11] * 1.5), 0.001))
x12 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[12] * 0.5), (budget_split[12] * 1.5), 0.001))
x13 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[13] * 0.5), (budget_split[13] * 1.5), 0.001))
x14 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[14] * 0.5), (budget_split[14] * 1.5), 0.001))
x15 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[15] * 0.5), (budget_split[15] * 1.5), 0.001))
x16 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[16] * 0.5), (budget_split[16] * 1.5), 0.001))
x17 = np.array(np.arange((budget_split[17] * 0.5), (budget_split[17] * 1.5), 0.001))

#Что я пробовал

#1) Сразу нашёл способ решения через itertools, но он не подойдёт.

z=m[0:4] #сделал из m список из 4х элементов
A = np.array(np.arange(0, 1, 0.05))
for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(A, 4):
    n = np.array(i)
    if budget_split[0]*0.5<=n[0]<=budget_split[0]*1.5\
            and sum(n)==1\
            and (n[0]+n[1])==0.4\
            and (n[0]+n[3]==0.5):
        y = sum(n) / sum(n * z)
        print(n)
        print(y)

#Для примера решение для n из 4х элементов с шагом 0.05 - и он срабатывает.
#А нужно подобрать возможные n из 18 элементов с шагом 0.001 - и тут случается неудача.
#Если я правильно понял, перебираемых вариантов получается слишком много - в результате инструмент бесконечно что-то делает, но ничего не показывает.
#Если указать условия, ситуация не облегчится.

#2) пытался подобрать n через 18-тикратные вложения (для каждого из 18 элементов):

for i0 in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(x0, 1):
    d0 = np.array(i0)
    for i1 in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(x1, 1):
        d1 = np.array(i1)
        и т.д.

#работает немногим лучше, чем itertools. Но как мне тут сказали, так делать глупо.
#вдобавок, стоит добавить условия для сумм некоторых элементов - компьютер погружается в вечные вычисления.


#Пожалуйста, подскажите, что я упускаю?
#есть ли способ выполнить данную задачу оптимально?
#возможно ли решить её используя Пайтон? или нужно что-то другое? потому что за Пайтон я взялся только из-за данной задачи :|.
#Если есть ссылки на полезную инфу - буду рад.
#Если понадобятся уточнения по условиям - пишите.
#Заранее Благодарю.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Не было сил читать какие-то комментарии к какой-то программе с описанием мук творчества ее автора. Но из того, что удалось понять, бегло просмотрев простыню каких-то фрагментов какого-то кода могу предположить, что автор пытается изобрести велосипед, который называется "задача линейного программирования" и для решения которой в Python и библиотеке scipy существует чудесная функция scipy.stats.linregress. И извращаться с восемнадцатикратным (!!!! -  первый раз в своей достаточно долгой программистской карьере вижу такое "чудо") вложением цикла не надо.

Если же я ошибся и это не линейное программирование, хотелось бы услышать от автора, чем же его задача отличается от этой классической постановки.

Comment: Да, похоже на задачу линейного программирования.
price_general = sum(n) / sum(n * m)
Пытался решить через sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression и после Вашей подсказки через scipy.stats.linregress. Это не совсем подходит.

Нужно подобрать все вариации n. Есть сложность - n должен выглядеть примерно так: 
budget_split_new = (x0,x1,x2,x3,...,x16,x17).  
Первую половину комментариев лучше прочесть - там указаны условия для элементов budget_split_new.

+убрал полотна вложений, детализировал первичное решение через itertools.

Comment: Так и не понял, в чем же отличия от классики. Там тоже ищется решение - не путем полного перебора, конечно, а более рационально. Что значит "выглядеть так: budget_split_new =..." непонятно.   Но в классике вы и получаете 18 значений представляющих единое решение. Условия, указанные у вас -  вообще азы линейного программирования. То что значения должны лежать в заданных диапазонах -  тоже. Так что же "не совсем подходит"?  Может все таки вы просто "не совсем разобрались в теме"?

Comment: Очевидно же, что в теме не разбираюсь совсем, иначе бы не писал сюда. "не совсем подходит" - не ясно, как в случае linregress задать диапазоны/условия и извлечь решение в виде 18 значений (привет, 18-тикратные вложения). При попытке разобраться, советуются другие инструменты scipy, включающие параметры bounds(диапазоны значений) и constraints(другие ограничения). Например, differential_evolution и minimize - в сравнении с linregress, сразу выводят 18 элементов и минимизированную цену.

Comment: Хотя differential_evolution даже при указанных bounds, выводит лишь минимальные значения 18 эл-тов. В minimize, при указанных bounds, 18 элементов выводятся оптимально. Но constraints нужно задать в виде словаря: напр, ({"type": "eq", "fun": lambda X: X.sum() - 1},{"type": "eq", "fun": lambda X: X[0]+X[1] - 0.25}). Когда словарь состоит из первого ограничения, инструмент выдаёт 18 эл-тов, составляющих в сумме 1. С добавлением 2ого ограничения начинает ругаться, что constraints не в виде 'Optional[dict]', хотя я и прописывал согласно примерам. Если проигнорировать - выводит базовое решение.